# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GET_ACTS_RULES_LIST_FOR_CLIENTS, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_ACTS_RULES_LIST_FOR_CLIENTS] 
     (@ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM DCMREPOSITORYV1..ACTS 
    WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS)

    SELECT * 
    FROM COMPLIANCE_FOR_CLIENTS 
    WHERE ACTSID IN (SELECT ID 
                     FROM ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS 
                     WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS))
    ORDER BY COMPLIANCE_CATEGORY_ID, ACTSID

    SELECT * 
    FROM STATE_CENTRAL_RULE_FOR_CLIENTS 
    WHERE ACTSID IN (SELECT ID 
                     FROM DCMREPOSITORYV1..ACTS 
                     WHERE Name IN (SELECT NAME FROM ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS))
    ORDER BY COMPLIANCE_CATEGORY_ID, ACTSID
END
```

Comment: END is there but still the same error is coming.

Comment: The parameter is lacking a type.

Comment: The correct syntax is to create a table type. Else declare a variable string and use it as a string instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CREATE PROCEDURE don`t need ()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql
+ add type variable @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS

```
    USE [TESTING]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_ACTS_RULES_LIST_FOR_CLIENTS] @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS VARCHAR(255)
    AS
    BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
SET  @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM DCMREPOSITORYV1..ACTS WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM '+@ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS+')';     
SET  @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT * FROM COMPLIANCE_FOR_CLIENTS WHERE ACTSID IN (SELECT ID FROM ' + @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS +' WHERE NAME IN (select NAME from ' + @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS + '))  ORDER BY COMPLIANCE_CATEGORY_ID,ACTSID ';

SET  @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT * FROM STATE_CENTRAL_RULE_FOR_CLIENTS WHERE ACTSID IN (SELECT ID FROM DCMREPOSITORYV1..ACTS WHERE Name IN (select NAME from ' + @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS +')) ORDER BY COMPLIANCE_CATEGORY_ID,ACTSID';

EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: By removing () showing error on BEGIN

Comment: Type @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS?

Comment: And how you use this variable(@ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS)?

Comment: @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS is a table. Is it a correct syntax for passing a table into procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Try corrected :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_ACTS_RULES_LIST_FOR_CLIENTS] 
 @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS readonly
    AS
    BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT * FROM DCMREPOSITORYV1..ACTS WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME FROM ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS)

SELECT * FROM COMPLIANCE_FOR_CLIENTS WHERE ACTSID IN (SELECT ID FROM ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS WHERE NAME IN (select NAME from ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS))
ORDER BY COMPLIANCE_CATEGORY_ID,ACTSID
SELECT * FROM STATE_CENTRAL_RULE_FOR_CLIENTS WHERE ACTSID IN (SELECT ID FROM DCMREPOSITORYV1..ACTS WHERE Name IN (select NAME from ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS))
ORDER BY COMPLIANCE_CATEGORY_ID,ACTSID

END
```

Corrections :

Invalid declared user defined table `@ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS`

Comment: @ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS is a table. Is it a correct syntax for passing a table into procedure?

Comment: @CharchitaWashimkar then pass it by `@ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS ACTS_FOR_CLIENTS readonly`

Comment: @CharchitaWashimkar you should learn about `user defined table type in stored procedure`..... http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/userdefined-table-type-and-table-valued-parameters-in-stored-procedure-to-reduce-the-code-size-in-code-behind-file